# How to find the days difference between two dates

Tags: vba, excel

I have been working on finding the Days difference between the dates found in Column A and column B. The dates in both columns are not constant thus I would need a code that would allow to read both dates in column A and B and find the Days difference between those two dates until the last row is empty.

Is there any code that I could use to find the Days difference between column A and B with a range of more than 500 rows?

Comment: [find the difference between 2 days](http://blog.pentalogic.net/2008/11/working-days-weekdays-holidays-sharepoint-calculated-columns/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using vba just enter the formula for the first row on C1 :

```
=ROUND(a1,0)-ROUND(b1,0)
```

Then just the formula to the end of exisiting rows.

If you insist using vba code use the simple code below:

```
   Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Range("c1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=ROUND(RC[-1],0)-ROUND(RC[-2],0)"
    Range("c1").AutoFill Destination:=Range("C1:C" & LastRow)
End Sub
```

Comment: Alright thank you! :)